# Extract tempdata or viewdata value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata, tempdata

how do i extract the value of tempdata or viewdata in javascript?
This returns "" even though there is a value being set. Is the syntax incorrect? I've tried without the '' as well as casting to string. Nothing seems to work...

```
var message = '@TempData["Message"]';
```

Answer (score 0):

> This returns "" even though there is a value being set.

Are you sure you have some value in `TempData`? I think you made some mistake in setting its value then.

Check this and then make sure you are doing it correctly.

- `TempData` is meant to be a very short-lived instance, and you should only use it
  during the current and the subsequent requests only.
- Since `TempData` works this way, you need to know for sure what the next request will be, and
  redirecting to another view is the only time you can guarantee this.
- Therefore, the only scenario where using `TempData` will reliably work is when
  you are redirecting.This is because a redirect kills the current request , then creates a
  new request on the server to serve the redirected view.
- Simply said, `Asp.Net MVC TempData dictionary` is used to share data between
  controller actions.
- The value of `TempData` persists until it is read or until the current user’s session times out.
- By default, the `TempData` saves its content to the session state.
- `TempData` values are marked for deletion when you read them. At the end of the request,
  any marked values are deleted.
- The benefit is that if you have a chain of multiple redirections it won’t cause `TempData` to
   be emptied the values will still be there until you actually use them, then they clear up after
   themselves automatically.

Comment: i'm sure the value is being set...just can't access it in jquery/javascript for some odd reason